# Website scrolling horizontally to the right

Tags: web, scroll, overflow, margin, elementor

I'm really scratching my head here. I'm trying to fix what i think is a overflow or margin issue with my megamenu  (Elementor Elementskit). One can scroll the website to the right.

If i remove the button (Login button in the top right corner), the scroll dissapears. So, i'm guessing something is "wrong" with my button, column or the megamenu it self. This only happens when i set the menubar to sticky.

I've tried to follow the other guides in here from people with similar problem, but i'm guessing mine is a bit different since i can't fix it with "overflow-x/y:hidden" and with "margin:" css.

I've opened a page for you to test, to see if you're able to help me out. This would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
This is related to the Wpmet ElementsKit MegaMenu. When removing the background of the MegaMenu to transparant. There's no way that i've found to change the max-width of of the panel it self without custom css.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I voted to close this question because the code with the problem is linked externally. Please [edit] this question to include the [minimal code that exhibits the issue](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. [Code linked externally may not be permanently available, and may not be licensed such that it can be used in answers](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/).

Answer (score 0):

You were right about overflow: super quick and super ugly fix (add this as CSS in the Customize Wordpress page):

```css
html { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

This doesn't actually remove the excess, it just doesn't let the user see it.

By the way: I tried to delete the button and many of its parent elements and the horizontal scrollbar still appears. Perhaps it's some CSS bug inside Elementor.

Comment: Seems like the megamenu had default `max-width: 1270px; left: -1093px;` which were throwing me off. If intended or not, i don't know.

This fixed it for me.
`.elementskit-megamenu-panel {

   max-width: 1150px !important;
   margin-left: 353px !important;

}`